# Changes to database evolutions not being detected

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, playframework-evolutions

I am currently trying to fix a faulty database evolution script--in fact, my first one (1.sql) for the web application. I applied the fix to the file, but the unfixed file is the one being run in both a live instance my Specs2 tests.

So, for instance, if I changed:

```
CREATE  TABLE dbname.Account ( ... );
```

to:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbname.Account ( ... );
```

in my evolution script, and then ran a test or ran the actual instance,

```
CREATE  TABLE dbname.Account ( ... );
```

would be what it still sees, as shown in the test log and in the live instance's error screen that shows up when an evolution is not applied correctly.

I've tried cleaning, recompiling, and deleting my target folder. None of those worked. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I hesitate to ask this, but I've done it before, as have other people who aren't complete idiots like me... Do you have more than one copy of the project and are you running the same one you're editing?

Comment: I don't have multiple copies of the project, so I should be running the same one I'm editing. I just double checked; I'm definitely running the correct project. If I change other files, sbt notices the change. It's just the evolution that it doesn't notice.

Comment: @JeffVanVranken - paste the first line of the `1.sql` file. Doesn't it start with: `# --- Created by Ebean DDL` ?

Comment: It, in fact, does. # --- First database schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folks over at the Play Framework Google Group got this one. Evolution scripts are also stored in your database schema in the table "play_evolutions". Wiping out the table fixed the issue. Wiping out the row would probably work too.